# Mock testing with nested function changes

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I am adding testing to a pipeline project, code is already written and in production so it cannot be changed to accommodate the tests.

In simplest terms, if I have a function like so:

```
def other_foo():
    return 1

def foo():
    res = other_foo()
    return res
```

In practicality, the `other_foo` call will return a variety of responses, but for testing, I want to create a fixed response to test `foo`.

So in my test I want to create a fixed response to `other_foo` of 2. and my test evaluation to be something like:

```
def test_foo():
    # some mocking or nesting handle here for other_foo
    res = foo()
    assert res == 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `patch` decorator from `unitest.mock` and patch your module local variable.

```py
from your.module import foo
from unitest.mock import patch

@patch('your.module.other_foo')
def test_foo(mock_other_foo):
    mock_other_foo.return_value = 3
    assert foo() == 3
    mock_other_foo.return_value = 42
    assert foo() == 42
```

You can find more information [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch) and [there](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#magic-mock).

Comment: Fantastic, thank you. Would this also work for multiple inner functions by passing more than one decorator ordered to match the test input?

Comment: Glad it helps you. Yes you can cumulate decorator, but be warned that the param injection will be in reversed order. You can also use `patch.multiple`